# Querying ManyToMany fields in Django

Tags: python, django

I`ve got these defined models

```
class Occupation(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    what_they_do = models.TextField(blank=True, default="")
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill)
    knowledge = models.ManyToManyField(Knowledge)
    abilities = models.ManyToManyField(Ability)
    technologies = models.ManyToManyField(Technology)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Where Knowledge, Technology, Skill, Ability are similar. I have used this structure.

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    element_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
       return self.title
```

In my template , currently I have:

```
<ul>
 {% for skill in ocuppation.skills.all %}
    <li>{{skill.title}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

but {{ skill.title }} is blank.

In my views.py , I have defined this :

```
def detail(request, pk):
   possible_occupation = Occupation.objects.filter(code=pk)
   occupation = possible_occupation[0] if len(possible_occupation) == 1 else None
   if occupation is not None:
       context = {
           'occupation': occupation
       }
       return render(request, 'careers/detail.html', context)
    else:
       return HttpResponseNotFound("No hay datos")
```

When I use the debugger I can see that occupation.skills, occupation.abilities ... are None.
If I check an occupation object in django admin , everything seems ok, but i can´t use them in templates.

Can anyone help?
Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Are you sure that `pk` has to be equal to  `code`?

Comment: Typo: `{% for skill in ocuppation.skills.all %}`. It should be: `{% for skill in occupation.skills.all %}`

Comment: I have misspelled occupation in template. With {% for skill in occupation.skills.all %} it works good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misspelled `occupation` in your template.

```
{% for skill in ocuppation.skills.all %}
```

It should be

```
{% for skill in occupation.skills.all %}
```

Here's a tip for debugging next time. When the for loop didn't print anything, I would try to include the queryset I was looping over.

```
{{ ocuppation.skills.all }}
```

and if that didn't work, try the instance itself

```
{{ ocuppation }}
```

Then I would know that the problem is with the variable `ocuppation`, not the many to many field. Hopefully I would then spot the misspelling.